# Global sections of higher direct images

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, abelian-varieties, class-field-theory

If $f : X\to V$ is a smooth proper map of smooth schemes, what are the global sections of

- $R^if_{fppf, *}\mu_p$
- $R^if_{fppf, *}\mathbb{G}_{\rm m}$

I was reading Milne's book "Arithmetic duality", but this is never clearly explained. I know both sheaves are the fppf sheaves associated to the presheaves

$$W\mapsto H^i_{fppf}(X_W, A)$$
$A = \mu_p,\mathbb{G}_{\rm m}$, but the global sections of a this presheaf cannot be the global sections of $R^if_*A$. Am I right? There can be more than one presheaf, with different global sections, with same associated sheaf.

Comment: Let $i = 1$ and $A = \mathbf{G}_{\rm m}$. Then $R^1f_{\rm fppf, *}\mathbf{G}_{\rm m}$ is representable in algebraic spaces, by work of Artin. The representing object is denoted $\text{Pic}_{X/V}$, and it is a separated algebraic space locally of finite type over $V$. The global sections of $R^1f_{\rm fppf, *}\mathbf{G}_{\rm m}$ are $\text{Pic}_{X/V}(V)$, and I'm not sure I can give a better description. Note that not all sections come from the class of a relative line bundle on $X$, unless an obstruction in the Brauer gp of $X$ vanishes.

Comment: As you can see, an answer to this question is already quite nontrivial for $i = 1$ and $A = \mathbf{G}_{\rm m}$. It is still an open problem, posed by Artin (in general) whether $R^1f_{\rm fppf, *}\mu_p$ is representable in algebraic spaces, although there should be papers of Lieblich addressing this. For higher degrees, total mystery.

Comment: @user113453. "It is still an open problem, posed by Artin (in general) whether $R^1f_{\text{fppf},*}\mu_p$ is representable in algebraic spaces."  I am just clarifying: do you  mean that this is open for morphisms more general than those specified by the OP?  Since the OP specifies that $f$ is smooth and proper, it is cohomologically flat in degree $0$.  Thus the Kummer sequence realizes $R^1f_{\text{fppf},*}\mu_p$ as the $p$-torsion in the relative Picard, i.e., the fiber product of the zero section and the $p$-power morphism.

Comment: By the way, there is a theory of Kato that interprets *part* of the groups $R^i f_{\text{fppf},*}\mu_p,$ $i>1,$ in terms of something like the de Rham complex.  Part of this is discussed in Serre's *Galois cohomology* where he discusses the $p$-torsion in Brauer groups, as well as his article, "Cohomologie galoisienne: progr\`es et probl\`emes."  I believe that  Philippe Gille is writing a book on Galois cohomology and cohomological dimension that explains Kato's theory.